# LyX:Remove Numbering of SubFigures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, lyx, subfloats

I want to remove the LyX Subfigures from the List of Figures. I have searched a lot, and although I find lots of LaTeX answers, I cannot find anything related to LyX.

I followed the instructions on the LyX site to get sub-figures for my PhD Thesis: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Figures#subfigures

I end up with something looking like this:

[image: LyX Design of Subfigures]

This works, and taking an example from my rendered PDF, I get this:

[image: Rendered Subfigures]

My only issue is, I **don't want** the captionless subfigures to appear in the List of Figures, such as this:

[image: Rendered List of Figures]

A point in the right direction would be awesome! I'm pretty close to submitting and this is my only outstanding issue!

Thanks!

**EDIT1**

The third image shows the List of Figures as rendered in the PDF. You can see multiple empty lines of ((a)) and ((b)). I wish to just see the entry for Figure 1.7 in the List of Figures, without the two subfigures shown.

The Document Class is currently Report (Standard Class). Articles don't have chapters.

Here's a cut down example as requested. It has some preamble from my thesis, but the text has been removed.

```
    #LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
    \lyxformat 508
    \begin_document
    \begin_header
    \save_transient_properties true
    \origin unavailable
    \textclass report
    \begin_preamble
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    %\usepackage{refcheck}
    %\hyphenation{}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \newtheorem{mydef}{Proposition}[chapter]
    \end_preamble
    \use_default_options false
    \maintain_unincluded_children false
    \language british
    \language_package none
    \inputencoding utf8
    \fontencoding global
    \font_roman "default" "default"
    \font_sans "default" "default"
    \font_typewriter "default" "default"
    \font_math "auto" "auto"
    \font_default_family default
    \use_non_tex_fonts false
    \font_sc false
    \font_osf false
    \font_sf_scale 100 100
    \font_tt_scale 100 100
    \graphics default
    \default_output_format default
    \output_sync 0
    \bibtex_command default
    \index_command default
    \paperfontsize default
    \spacing double
    \use_hyperref false
    \papersize a4paper
    \use_geometry true
    \use_package amsmath 2
    \use_package amssymb 2
    \use_package cancel 1
    \use_package esint 2
    \use_package mathdots 0
    \use_package mathtools 1
    \use_package mhchem 0
    \use_package stackrel 1
    \use_package stmaryrd 1
    \use_package undertilde 1
    \cite_engine basic
    \cite_engine_type default
    \biblio_style plain
    \use_bibtopic false
    \use_indices false
    \paperorientation portrait
    \suppress_date false
    \justification true
    \use_refstyle 0
    \index Index
    \shortcut idx
    \color #008000
    \end_index
    \leftmargin 4cm
    \topmargin 2.5cm
    \rightmargin 2.5cm
    \bottommargin 2.5cm
    \headsep 0.2cm
    \footskip 1cm
    \secnumdepth 3
    \tocdepth 3
    \paragraph_separation indent
    \paragraph_indentation default
    \quotes_language english
    \papercolumns 1
    \papersides 1
    \paperpagestyle default
    \tracking_changes false
    \output_changes false
    \html_math_output 0
    \html_css_as_file 0
    \html_be_strict false
    \end_header

    \begin_body

    \begin_layout Standard
    \begin_inset FloatList figure

    \end_inset


    \end_layout

    \begin_layout Chapter
    Test Chapter
    \end_layout

    \begin_layout Subsubsection
    Some Stuff
    \begin_inset CommandInset label
    LatexCommand label
    name "subsec:example"

    \end_inset


    \end_layout

    \begin_layout Standard
    \begin_inset Float figure
    wide false
    sideways false
    status open

    \begin_layout Plain Layout
    \begin_inset ERT
    status collapsed

    \begin_layout Plain Layout


    \backslash
    centering
    \end_layout

    \end_inset


    \begin_inset Float figure
    wide false
    sideways false
    status open

    \begin_layout Plain Layout
    \align center
    \begin_inset Graphics
        filename example1.png
        lyxscale 50
        width 78text%

    \end_inset


    \begin_inset Caption Standard

    \begin_layout Plain Layout

    \end_layout

    \end_inset


    \end_layout

    \begin_layout Plain Layout

    \end_layout

    \end_inset


    \begin_inset Float figure
    wide false
    sideways false
    status open

    \begin_layout Plain Layout
    \align center
    \begin_inset Graphics
        filename example2.png
        lyxscale 30
        width 20text%

    \end_inset


    \end_layout

    \begin_layout Plain Layout
    \begin_inset Caption Standard

    \begin_layout Plain Layout

    \end_layout

    \end_inset


    \end_layout

    \begin_layout Plain Layout

    \end_layout

    \end_inset


    \end_layout

    \begin_layout Plain Layout
    \begin_inset Caption Standard

    \begin_layout Plain Layout
    Single caption for both figures.
    \begin_inset CommandInset label
    LatexCommand label
    name "fig:example_fig"

    \end_inset


    \end_layout

    \end_inset


    \end_layout

    \end_inset


    \end_layout

    \begin_layout Standard
    Figure 
    \begin_inset CommandInset ref
    LatexCommand ref
    reference "fig:example_fig"

    \end_inset

     depicts an example of some stuff.
    \end_layout

    \end_body
    \end_document
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: With a default LyX document (`article` class)  the  list of figures do not show the subfigures. Moreover the float subfigures must be inside two frameless boxes (aka minipages) to maintain both in the same line (as showed in the PDF image, but not in the LyX screen image) so we do not have enough information about your document to reproduce the problem.  The MWE (the LyX file or the exported LaTeX source as seen in a plain text editor)  that Andrew asked, not only help to understand what you want, also what are you doing.

Comment: @Fran Thanks for the info. I followed the instructions on the LyX site [LyX>Figures>Subfigures](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Figures#subfigures) to create the top image, as shown in LyX. This renders as the second, with the third as presented in the List of Figures. I want to remove the subfigures.

Comment: Anyone? Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some experimentation, I found the following solution did what I was trying to do. I make no claims as to it being "the right" way to do it, but, it works - `pdflatex` doesn't complain about anything...

[image: LyX Layout of two side-by-side figures, captioned, but not listed in figures list]

This looks like the following in the built PDF:

[image: The rendered PDF]

Finally, how it listed in the list of figures. It appears as Figure 1.7, but the sub-figures are not mentioned.

[image]

Maybe this will help someone else, if they come across this thread. :)